# Issue with Texture Display in Cloned Project from GitHub Repository

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I cloned the project from GitHub repository ([line_follower_pkg](https://github.com/DougUOW/line_follower_pkg)), and I'm encountering an issue with the texture on the ground not displaying correctly. Despite following the right steps, the texture fails to appear as intended.
I tried if it was a path problem, but if the material is not found, gazebo just doesnt open and crashes.

[image]